# Which process is locking the camera?

Tags: battery, camera, reboot, processes

There is a problem with my UleFone Armor 2 with Android 7.0 Nougat:

After using the camera some times, it stops working due to the inability to connect to the camera.

I tried killing the camera application, but it does not yet unlock the camera. And the battery manager suggests that the camera was permanently on since the time it has stopped working.

**A simple reboot does solve that problem,** but rebooting is a seriois violation of an important Linux philosophy, which states that rebooting is never a good method of solving problems and should be avoided wherever possible.

Comment: Might help if you could explain what "using the camera" means in this context. In the past, there was e.g. an issue many barcode readers shared due to a bug in the camera API, which had exactly the described effect. Though that bug should have been fixed years ago, it could be something similar. So: Does this happen always when you use the camera, regardless of the app (camera app, barcode reader, video recorder …) – or only with a specific app?

Comment: @Izzy On the same page, custom ROMs for devices such as the I9300 notably suffered (and yet suffer) from camera bugs, ranging from being unable to connect to the camera, to apparently having something locking it, as in OP's case. Those issues, though, depend on drivers.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman has a point here – so you should also mention what ROM you're using (the official one, ow which custom ROM).

Comment: Official ROM. @Izzy.

Comment: @Izzy with the stock camera app when launching from lockscreen after many days without reboot, it happens.

Comment: Only then it happens – or is that just one of several cases?