# How to see, which app locks access to the camera?

Tags: applications, camera, permissions

My Android 7.0 phone has a flaw:
When using the camera often, and the phone's uptime climbs beyond 100 hours (launch camera, capture, lock screen), at one point, the camera viewfinder just freezes, and the camera application crashes.

Then, it fails to *connect* to the camera, while the battery monitor claims that the camera is still on, even when disabling the camera permissions for every single user and system app.

**Rebooting** does fix that problem, but rebooting to solve problems is considered as a **terrible violation of the Linux philosophy,** and only an emergency workaround.

How do I identify the application/service that locks the camera and kill it?
There is **only one rule:** must exclude rebooting.

Comment: Didn't you ask that just a few days ago: [Which process is locking the camera?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/193756/16575) It's a terrible violation of this sites policy to re-ask the same question ;)

Comment: @Izzy Whoops, I forgot it. I should have improved the phrasing of the previous one. I will do that tomorrow.

Comment: @Izzy I have confused it with a different forum I might have asked it on.